# Increment iterator when repeating key value in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Basically I just want each row of the table to hold the current key value, and the next. Is there a way to increment from inside the loop?

```
          <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in object">
              <td>
                  <strong>{{key}}</strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{value}}
              </td>
              <td>
                  <strong>{{key + 1}}</strong>
              </td>
              <td>
                  {{value + 1}}
              </td>
          </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the array through $index.

```
  <div ng-repeat="text in texts">
      {{texts[$index].title}}
      {{texts[$index+1].title}}
  </div>
```

I made a short [jsfiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/markuswaltre/mPqvn/)

Comment: I specifically need to iterate over an object and get the current key/value and the value of the next, not an array. I could definitely turn the object into an array though if this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, although I think it will just be blank for the last row:

```
      <td>
          {{ object[$index + 1].value }}   
      </td>
```